# Upload image from React Native App to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Is it possible to directly upload an image taken with the camera in a React Native App to a Google Cloud Bucket? If not, what would be the best approach?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I've found out that it is possible to directly upload an image to Google Cloud. But, I've not tested yet. Here's the link https://medium.com/google-cloud/upload-images-to-google-cloud-storage-with-react-native-and-expressjs-61b8874abc49. I hope it might help you.

Alternative solution is uploading to firebase storage using react-native-firebase. This is the way I used in my application.

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna try it!